# Can the cardinality of a power set ever be odd?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Can the cardinality of a power set ever be odd? If it can, what conditions must be met?

Comment: The power set of the empty set has one element.

Comment: And that's the only example, as the cardinality of the power set of a (finite) set with $n$ elements is $2^{n}$.

Comment: The cardinality of a set of $n$ members is $2^n$. The only case where this is odd is when $n=0$, i.e. the empty set.

Comment: Seeing how this is a particularly simple question, I'd like to know where it came up and what you tried to do in order to solve it.

Answer (score 5):

The power set of the empty set has 1 element, the empty set. $2^0=1$

EDIT: Credit as well to Tunococ, Andreas Caranti, and Mufasa for their comments. I guess I jumped the gun since this is my first answer!

Comment: You should give some credit to the user who posted this as a comment (since it looks almost identical).

Comment: @barakmanos, if users upvote an answer when there are more exhaustive replies in previous comments, there's little one can do.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible for finite non empty sets. This is because you have $2$ possibles "truth values" : true or false.

More precisely, let $E$ a finite set with $n≥1$. Then the power set has $2^n$ elements which is even if $n≠0$.

Let $A \subseteq E$. For each $x \in E$, either $x\in A$ or $x \not \in A$. In other words, for each of the $n$ elements, you have $2$ possibilites : either it belongs to $A$ or it doesn't.

Therefore you have 
$\underbrace{2 \cdot 2 \cdots 2 \cdot 2}_{n \text{ times}} = 2^n$
 different possibilities, corresponding to the $2^n$ different possible subsets of $E$.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize some of the previous answers and comments here in mathematical notation:

> Can the cardinality of a power set ever be odd?

$S=\emptyset \implies P(S)=\{\emptyset\} \implies |P(S)|=1 \implies |P(S)|\equiv1\pmod2$

> If it can, what conditions must be met?

$|P(S)|\equiv1\pmod2 \implies |P(S)|=1 \implies P(S)=\{\emptyset\} \implies S=\emptyset$